# Access values using {{#each}} in a one dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, template-engine

I've found a lot of examples of using the `{{#each}}` helper to iterate over multi-dimensional arrays, but I can't figure out how to access each value in a one-dimensional array.

For example, take this array:

```
skills: ['Design', 'Development', 'HTML5', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
```

How do I output each item, in a helper like below?

```
template: Handlebars.compile(
'<div>' + 
    '{{#each skills}} {{ the_item_output }} {{/each}}' +
'</div>'
),
```

What do I need to put in placed of `{{ the_item_output }}` to see the actual item?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration

Comment: multi-dimensional array, i imagine, is the wrong term here

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
{{#each skills}}
  <li>{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I think you want skills, not people

Answer (score 4):

An array of scalar values should make use of the [*Simple Iterators*](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#iterators) grammar. You need to declare an `#each` block on the `skills` property.

The placeholder for each value can be either `{{this}}` or `{{.}}`.

You need to use the following template:

```js
{{#each skills}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Alternatively, you can use `#list`.

```js
{{#list skills}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
{{/list}}
```

### Example

```js
function listToHTML(items) {
  return '<ul>' + items.map(function(item) {
    return '<li>' + item + '</li>';
  }).join('') + '</ul>';
}

Handlebars.registerHelper({
  scalar_list_raw : function(items) {
    return listToHTML(items);
  },
  
  scalar_list_safe_string: function(items) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(listToHTML(items));
  },
});

var data = {
  skills: [ 'Design', 'Development', 'HTML5', 'CSS', 'JavaScript' ],
};

$(function() {
  var source = $("#skills-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

  $('body').append(template(data));
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.3/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="skills-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h2>Skills - [Block] Each</h2>
  <ul>
    {{#each skills}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  <h2>Skills - [Helper] SafeString</h2>
  {{scalar_list_safe_string skills}}

  <h2>Skills - [Helper] Raw HTML</h2>
  {{{scalar_list_raw skills}}}
</script>
```